# Code design, method parameters

Tags: java, wrapper, lwjgl

I'm designing a wrapper for LWJGL and I've got a wrapper class that wraps all of the methods in a type-safe way. However, I've run into an issue which I've never really thought about before. Consider I have this method, which accepts an enum value and an int.

```
public static void glBindBuffer(Target target, int id) {
    GL15.glBindBuffer(target.glValue, id);
}
```

I have a class which handles OpenGL buffer objects in an object orientated manner. It has a static method (it's static because it handles a global state) which simply detaches a buffer object from a target. I have two options; I could either accept a BufferObject instance or a Target as a parameter, like so:

```
public static void detach(Target target) {
    GL.glBindBuffer(target, 0);
}

public static void detach(BufferObject bufferObject) {
    GL.glBindBuffer(bufferObject.getTarget(), 0);
}
```

Which is better to do?

**Note:** I don't want the user to have to directly call GL.glBindBuffer(..)

Comment: How about `bufferObject.detach()` if you want to use buffers in an object oriented manner?

Comment: Implement both and let one call the other one.

Comment: @micha The class as a whole handles buffer objects in an object orientated manner, however binding 0 to the buffer object is not specific to each buffer object. It would also give the user the idea that's you have to detach all buffer objects from the target, which is not the case.

Comment: @helpermethod Any reason why I should do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **helpermethod** mentioned, the best solution is to wrap one method to the other like this:

```
public static void detach(Target target) {
    GL.glBindBuffer(target, 0);
}

public static void detach(BufferObject bufferObject) {
    detach(bufferObject.getTarget());
}
```

So you're supporting both ways to the programmer.

And if you have to change your `glBindBuffer` behavior, you only have to rewrite the `detach(Target)` method!

Comment: I'll consider this. It seems to solve my concern over ease-of-use, however I'm wondering whether it might cause confusion.

Comment: That sort of method overloading is common in libraries, shouldn't cause any confusion as the methods do the same thing.

Comment: Okay I'll go with this then (you've convinced me :)), since the general opinion seems to be to use both.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going for the first version:

```
public static void detach(Target target) {
    GL.glBindBuffer(target, 0);
}
```

The reason is that this decouples the `BufferObject` from the `detach()` method. This makes your code a little bit more flexible, and makes testing easier.

Comment: That was my original thought, however my argument against doing so was because of ease-of-use.